# Angular Storage get return undefined

Tags: angular

Desenvolvendo um APP Ionic / Angular e estou usando o storage para salvar e recuperar informação do token do usuário. O problema é que estou tendo que chamar/instanciar N´s vezes uma função para recuperar o token e mesmo assim algumas vezes o token não é retornado.

Na tela inicial eu simulo um login com os dados que preciso:

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
    
private _Storage: Storage

this._Storage.set('X-Access-Token', 'f27bf5399b81c701bd9d6158ca67bb58');
this._Storage.set('isLogged', 'true');
this._Router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
```

Para conseguir recuperar o X-Access-Token no compoment dashboard (e todos os outros componentes) tenho que chamar a função GetAccessToken com ngOnInit, e depois de dentro da função principal de cada componente.

```
    XAccessToken: any;

    ngOnInit() { 
       this.GetXAccessToken();
    }
    
     GetXAccessToken() {
        this._Storage.get('X-Access-Token').then((token) => {
          this.XAccessToken = token;
        });
      }
    
    ionViewDidEnter() {
        this.GetChannelsFollowed();  
      }
    
      async GetChannelsFollowed() {
        this.GetXAccessToken();
     ....
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

O que acontece é que o o get storage é um requisição assíncrona, então em alguns momentos não recebo a resposta em tempo de dar continuidade nas próximas funções, e gera o erro. Para resolver o problema criei um observable e solicito o token através deste.

```
export interface ICredential {
    IsLogged?: boolean;
    XAccessToken?: string;
}

  Session(): Observable<ICredential> {
    return new Observable<ICredential>(observer => {
      observer.next(this._ICredential);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Quando você usa o storage.get, ele já valida para você se existe ou não, não precisando validar se ele é definido ou não.
Tente:

```
this.storage.get('X-Access-Token').then((token) => {
  return (token);
});
return('');
```

Assim sempre terá um retorno dentro do token, bastando compara-lo depois